Has any Republican chapter denounced the Colorado GOP for its anti-pride flag tweet?
Has the national Party or any state chapter of the Republican Party denounced the Colorado GOP's tweet urging people to "burn all #pride flags"?

The answer to the headline question is "yes", but maybe only at the county level so far.
Here is a Facebook post from the Jefferson County Republican Party with a statement calling for the responsible state chairman to resign. The statement claims support from "numerous Colorado Republican County Chairs" and other party officials.

The Facebook post was unavailable when I looked but there is a report by Axios.

Hmm, FB link still works for me. The Advocate also reports it in detail.
